# 2 domains with 2 certificates, 1 public IP, 1 nginx server

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

I hope you can help me out here because I cannot figure out why this is happening. I have the following 2 domains:

- alpha.com
- beta.com

they both pointing to same server IP:

- x.x.x.x

I have a single nginx running on this server. On my firewall, i have ports 80 and 443 forwarded to this server's internal IP;

- 192.168.1.2

both of the domains have their own certificates.

Here are the server configuration for both of these domains:

- alpha.com: http://pastebin.com/u9absNMe
- beta.com: http://pastebin.com/m7dV2cqk

Problem: The problem here is that when I go to alpha.com, the sever redirects me to http.s://alpha.com and loads the content of alpha.com, so far it's great. When i open a new tab on my browser and type beta.com, the url on my browser changes to http.s://beta.com but loads the content of alpha.com.

How would I tell nginx to server the right directory for each domain based on which URL was typed in the browser and still keep the https?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your virtual hosts are pointing to the same port on your loop-back address.

What do you have listening at `http://127.0.0.1:2368`?

You need to configure that service to listen on two different ports and proxy each nginx vhost to it's own unique port.

Comment: Thanks @MyNameIsBoring. There is no service listening on that port. I removed the port. Now, after reloading nginx, my alpha.com site is not loading either. Both domains show the right certificate but no content is loaded. Initially when I had the port, at least the alpha.com would load with the right content.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04) this post on Digital Ocean.

It is possible through [Server Name Identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) (SNI). This is a relative recent addition to SSL. Previously it was not possible for two (or more) different domain names to use the same IP address for https access.

Comment: Yes, I found that article and run the "nginx -V" command and it says that "TLS SNI support enabled"

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found my own mistake, I had ghost blogging platform running on one of the domains and wordpress on the other. I resolved the issue by removing the following code from the nginx configuration file for the wordpress site.

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;`

FYI, the port 2368 that @MyNameIsBoring mentioned is the port ghost uses, so I had setup reverse proxy to server it on 80 and 443. Obviously, that does not work for wordpress, by removing that portion of the code, all start working as they should.

Comment: I was just about to comment and tell you to remove that whole `location` block if there was nothing being served from there.